# How to encrypt a password and save it in MySQL database.

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, authentication, encryption

Now I am just saving the password as it is

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string userName = Label13.Text;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        MySqlConnection connectionString = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=surelyknown;Uid=root");
        connectionString.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
adapter.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_user (FirstName,LastName,Email,U_Password,CompanyName,UserPermission,PhoneNumber,Created,Modified,Active,CreatedBy,tbl_organisation_OrganisationID) VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@U_Password,@CompanyName,@UserPermission,@PhoneNumber,@Created,@Modified,@Active,@CreatedBy,@tbl_organisation_OrganisationID)", connectionString);
    adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstName.Text;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Surname.Text;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Email.Text;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@U_Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password.Text;
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(nID);
```

and when the user login to the website how can the encrypted password used to do authentication. i want to do the decryption in the server side itself. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should [salt and hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/why-is-it-always-hash-salt-password-that-we-recommend) your passwords. When you say you want to do that on the server side, do you mean on the database server side, or the application server?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, `hash + salt` your password, **save the hash** into the database, do not save the clear-text password.

When the user logs into your system, hash the same password from him with the salt, compare that hash with the hash saved to your database, if they match, then your user is authenticated.

`Hashing` your password hides the real password from any successful attempts to hack into your password.

`Salting` your password with another arbitrary value saves you a margin from dictionary based brute force attacks.

[See OWASP for `Salt + Hashing + High number of iterations` technique](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java)
This is in Java, but i believe the theory covered is portable across any languages / implementations.

Comment: How about the salt? Where to store the salt? Static inside the application? On the database? On a property file?